# 1280 x 800 tablet size - is it tvdpi or xhdpi? or mdpi size?

Tags: android, assets, resolution

1280 x 800 tablet size - is it tvdpi or xhdpi? or mdpi size? I guess it's according to the device, but I need to understand for sure to know if it is a base mdpi size for the assets or no. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Density is given by screen size & resolution, so without knowing the screen size you cannot tell the density just from the resolution.

Answer (score 7):

A device with a 1280x800 px resolution could be any of tvdpi, xhdpi, mdpi or any other. Which one is it will depend on the physical size of the screen. A 6.3 inch screen with that particular resolution would be hdpi, 9.4 inch would be mdpi, 4.7 in would be xhdpi, etc.

xhdpi, mdpi and so on, are not sizes. Those are generalized densities. They tell you, in approximation, how many pixels there are per inch, for a particular device.

You could check if [Device Metrics](https://design.google.com/devices/) lists your device of interest.

I just noticed, that you say it's a tablet. This narrows the possibilities, but still isn't definite. It could be, for example, a 7 inch tvdpi device like Nexus 7 '12, or a 10 inch mdpi device like Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.

Comment: my goal is to create a generalised template for all the tablet screens. We have 1280 x 800 tablets, but it shows smth different from what I've designed and style guided, because it recalculates it according to some formula that moves/resizes objects according to the screen size/density. Also I'm trying to understand which is the most common ratio for the tablets, what would be the best to use as a base.

Comment: @Rastamamka You should use *density independent pixels* (dp) instead of *pixels* (px) when designing layouts. Layouts should be designed based on the available screen width, expressed in dp. You can read more about [layout, units and responsive UI](https://material.google.com/layout/principles.html) and download [layout templates for tablets](https://material.google.com/resources/layout-templates.html#layout-templates-tablet).

Answer (score 1):

values-sw720dp          10.1” tablet 1280x800 mdpi

values-sw600dp          7.0”  tablet 1024x600 mdpi

values-sw480dp          5.4”  480x854 mdpi 
values-sw480dp          5.1”  480x800 mdpi

values-xxhdpi           5.5"  1080x1920 xxhdpi
values-xxhdpi           5.5"  1440x2560 xxhdpi

values-xhdpi            4.7”   1280x720 xhdpi 
values-xhdpi            4.65”  720x1280 xhdpi

values-hdpi             4.0” 480x800 hdpi
values-hdpi             3.7” 480x854 hdpi

values-mdpi             3.2” 320x480 mdpi

values-ldpi             3.4” 240x432 ldpi
values-ldpi             3.3” 240x400 ldpi
values-ldpi             2.7” 240x320 ldpi

Answer (score 0):

Majority of tablets are mdpi anyway. And besides pixels size it's better to add screen size information. And "What's my Size?" app shows dpi type well.

Comment: thank you so much) I will try the app. my goal is to create a generalised template for all the tablet screens. We have 1280 x 800 tablets, but it shows smth different from what I've designed and style guided, because it recalculates it according to some formula that moves/resizes objects according to the screen size/density. Also I'm trying to understand which is the most common ratio for the tablets, what would be the best to use as a base.